# Erro ao usar TDD com Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

Olá,

Estou começando a estudar sobre TDD com Ruby on Rails e estou seguindo um tutorial do Nando Viera[[1](https://nandovieira.com.br/tdd-no-rails-unit-tests)], mas ao tentar executar um rake:test:units o seguinte erro é retornado:

```
UserTest#test_truth:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Field 'name' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `users` (`id`) VALUES (980190962)
```

Segue a minha migration:

```
  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     create_table :users do |t|
       t.column :name, :string, :null => false
       t.column :email, :string, :null => false
       t.column :password, :string, :null => false
     end
   end

   def self.down
     drop_table :users
   end
end
```

E o teste:

require 'test_helper'

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :users

  def test_truth
    assert true
  end

end
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, estou utilizando o rails 4.2, ao criar o modelo ele cria o arquivo users.yml dentro da pasta test/fixtures/users.yml, omo este arquivo estava criado sem nenhum padrão do modelo o erro citado a cima era aprensentado.Para mais informações sobre como criar/editar o arquivo yml: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

Comment: Qual versão do Rails vc esta usando? Pelo jeito da escritá me parece  uma versão antiga.